# {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}

Tags: c#

I was unable to find a proper solution to this error. I was trying to integrate my virtual machine created in the azure environment to the MVC asp.net application. I was trying to use this as an API to integrate but the link seems to be not working. Could anyone let me know the exact solution for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Not enough information to provide help